# Loading Zurb Foundation Sites via SystemJS

Tags: zurb-foundation, systemjs

We are having some trouble with getting the [Zurb Foundation Sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/) JavaScript plugins to initialize correctly when imported via SystemJS.

We have installed jQuery and Foundation via JSPM:

```
jspm install jquery    
jspm install npm:foundation-sites
```

Then we initialize the application like this:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import foundation from 'foundation-sites';
jQuery(document).foundation();
```

When we then try to get [Sticky](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html) to work for example, the CSS classes are added (via JS). But the script doesn't work, and we get no errors.

When we then bundle the application via JSPM the script works like it should. So it feels like we have got some problem with dependencies not loading. We have tried figuring out how to [shim dependencies](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#shim-dependencies) in SystemJS, without any luck.

Is there maybe someone that have gotten this to work?

Comment: Having the same issue here. I'm also using SystemJS. I added foundation.min.js as foundation to my SystemJS loader. So I would expect to import it in TypeScript as foundation. How can I make this clear to typescript where the module comes from, because it seams to me that this somehow isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of version and the last that now works looks like this

```
import "jquery";
import "foundation-sites";
```

Calling foundation than works like in the question with `jQuery(document).foundation();`

Comment: Can I do this in October? If i get the above process properly, I add the imports to my component, then where do I call the `jQuery(document).foundation();`?, in the HTML?

Comment: You can do it every month you want o_O
Calling init for foundation should be called somwhere you are sure the DOM is fully loaded. So for example inside an $(document).ready() or an angular ngOnInit(). Depends on how the JavaScript on your page works.

Comment: Can you please help with an example?